# docker wants to login for a free image

Tags: docker

I don't know what to do. My Dockerfile is very simple, it's just one line. Why is the system not able to load the image? Why is there a try to login? it's just a free image.

Here is my output, the Dockerfile is listed in it.

```
user@server:~/test$ sudo docker build .
[+] Building 0.4s (3/3) FINISHED                                                                                                                          docker:default
 => [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                                                                                                                0.0s
 => => transferring dockerfile: 75B                                                                                                                                 0.0s
 => [internal] load .dockerignore                                                                                                                                   0.0s
 => => transferring context: 2B                                                                                                                                     0.0s
 => ERROR [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/python:3.11-slim                                                                                           0.4s
------
 > [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/python:3.11-slim:
------
Dockerfile:1
--------------------
   1 | >>> FROM python:3.11-slim
   2 |
--------------------
ERROR: failed to solve: python:3.11-slim: error getting credentials - err: exit status 1, out: `Cannot autolaunch D-Bus without X11 $DISPLAY`
user@server:~/test$
```

Here the docker version output:

```
Client: Docker Engine - Community
 Version:           24.0.5
 API version:       1.43
 Go version:        go1.20.6
 Git commit:        ced0996
 Built:             Fri Jul 21 20:35:36 2023
 OS/Arch:           linux/amd64
 Context:           default

Server: Docker Engine - Community
 Engine:
  Version:          24.0.5
  API version:      1.43 (minimum version 1.12)
  Go version:       go1.20.6
  Git commit:       a61e2b4
  Built:            Fri Jul 21 20:35:36 2023
  OS/Arch:          linux/amd64
  Experimental:     false
 containerd:
  Version:          1.6.22
  GitCommit:        8165feabfdfe38c65b599c4993d227328c231fca
 runc:
  Version:          1.1.8
  GitCommit:        v1.1.8-0-g82f18fe
 docker-init:
  Version:          0.19.0
  GitCommit:        de40ad0
```

Comment: What operating system is this?

Comment: Try running `docker pull python:3.11-slim` first. Then try building the image again.

Comment: That looks like you have a credential helper that would be prompting you via the GUI. Check your `~/.docker/config.json` to see what helper it's using. Take care not to share any of the `"auth": ...` lines from this file since they are base64 encoded credentials.

Comment: @ msrumon: thanks, that worked for me.  But what was the problem?
@BMitch: Why want docker to authenticate against someone!? In my case it isn't necessery I think.

Comment: Do you need to run `sudo` to access docker? Have you looked at the contents of your `~/.docker/config.json` for your user and for root to see if there are credential helpers?

Comment: @BMitch: Yes I use sudo and there are credential helpers by default.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> error getting credentials - err: exit status 1, out: `Cannot autolaunch D-Bus without X11 $DISPLAY`
> ```

This error is coming from docker running the credential helper and failing. The credential helper requires X windows access (the GUI interface) and `sudo` is not passing through access to your GUI (assuming there is one).

Your options include:

1. Don't run commands with `sudo` if you don't need it. Adding a user to the `docker` group gives them access to the root docker API without a password. Depending on your environment, that may be a good or bad thing.
2. Not using that credential helper, or configuring the credential helper to not need the GUI. If the credential helper is removed from the file, docker will store logins in base64 encoded text per registry.
3. Passing through X access to the `sudo` command. This requires passing through the `$DISPLAY` variable, and possibly configuring `xauth` to allow the connection. See [other answers](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/476290/x11-forwarding-does-not-work-if-su-to-another-user) for details on that.

Authentication is used when available because docker doesn't know what access you have to the image until it tries to pull it. It may need your credential for a private image. And pulling public images on Docker Hub counts against a rate limit that is increased by logging in.